# Epigenetic marks

Tags: epigenetics

I was lately researching epigenetics and the current research on age reversal. Because epigenetic processes are influenced by the environment and can vary over time, I wanted to know if all epigenetic marks and mechanisms, including those that play a key part in cell differentiation, are reversible?
I am extremely keen to learn about this and any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology! When you say "reversible", what do you mean exactly? All chemical processes are theoretically reversible. It would help to know more about what specifically you have read, and what does not answer your question from e.g. a google search or wikipedia page. For example, I find multiple resources on this topic by google (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3411986/, https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5137275/). Is there something specifically that you don't understand? Otherwise this question will be difficult to answer as it is quite broad.

Comment: I second the comments of @MaximilianPress but would ask you whether you know what “epigenetic tags” are in chemical terms. Because if you do not, you need to find out before you are in a position to ask here about their specific reversal because it is unlikely that you will understand an answer. Do you?

Comment: @David Sir, yes I studied them  and I understand them

Comment: @Maximillian Press Sir, I was curious if the epigenetic processes that drive cell differentiation and aging may be reversed. Can we undo all of the aging-causing epigenetic mechanisms?

Comment: @AIA that is good information to have in the question, but it is still very generic. There are many kinds of changes that people call epigenetic that play roles in development/differentiation, and yes they are reversible in some sense at the biochemical level. However, this does not necessarily have any relevance to aging. It would be helpful to know more specifics about what you have read and what specific questions remain unanswered. This is too broad to answer as is.

Comment: @Maximilian Press Sorry sir, I am not delivering clear information. Basically, I am making a video for a competition on the topic of slowing down and reversing aging with epigenetics. I read David Sinclair and other scientists' researches about it. So I just want to clarify that if we are reversing aging, so it mean that we are changing our epigenome and reversing some epigenetic marks? so I want to clarify is this right. Sir, if you have references to any research articles that would help me in getting great insight into this topic, i will be thankful if you can share them

Comment: To some extent, there are people who believe that we can reverse aging by reversing epigenetic marks. I don't know that I believe this, but there is certainly an academic literature on it. Notably, some of the same epigenetic marks associated with aging are also associated with tumor suppression, so reversing marks is not necessarily always a great idea. Here is a link to an article, that in turn links to a study. I wouldn't necessarily trust it, but it should lead you to more information: https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-02638-w